# RESTful API design: filter (parameter) vs locate (uri) for association

Tags: php, api, rest

I am torn between these two:

- `/v1/category/{id}/articles`
- `/v1/articles?category={id}`

Since `{id}` identify a category, should the first design **always** be chosen? the confusion here is that article:category isn't **N:1** relation but **N:M**. Does RESTful design have any guideline on N:M relationship?

---

**Update:** another scenario to consider: we also have collections for users to `like` or `save` articles, how should we choose under such scenario?

- `/v1/user/{id}/articles?type=save`
- `/v1/articles?user={id}&type=save`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Path vs. Query

Both

```
/v1/category/{id}/articles
```

and

```
/v1/articles?category={id}
```

are valid and there is no strict rule for one against the other. In fact, *both* could easily exist in the same RESTful application.

The cardinality of the article-category relationship does not matter since both approaches support only *one* category.

### Like

If you want to *like* an article, use a resource you `POST` to.

```
POST /likes/articles/1234
```

with a body of

```
{
  "user": "Joe"
}
```

would create a new like of user `Joe` for article `1234`. You could `GET` the likes for an article:

```
GET /likes/article/1234
```

which could return

```
["Joe", "Jane"]
```

if both `Joe` and `Jane` like the article.

### Save

To *save* or *alter* an existing article, use `PUT` on it with the new representation.

```
PUT /article/1234
```

with body

```
{
  "title": "The Article Title",
  "content": "What the article is about"
}
```

**Do not use query parameters like `save` when HTTP verbs exist.**

Comment: thx for the first part, though my reasearch seems to suggest the former choice is far more popular, maybe the choice can be made with respect to internal system. for the second part i am essentially asking the same question but sightly different context, so i am looking at GET request (read), not POST/PUT.

Comment: 'like' and 'save' sound like actions that *change* server state. `GET` is the wrong HTTP verb for this. Use `POST` or `PUT`.

Comment: I was asking for api design on GET-ting the user-liked/saved articles, not adding or modifying them :)